# NVD3 - tickFormat for currency issues

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

Right now I'm trying to figure out how to make my y-Axis look better for currency. You can notice two issues with the following picture:

1. The top and bottom numbers include ugly decimal places
2. The "G" should be a "B" for billion

[image: Line Graph using NVD3]

What can I do to clean this kind of stuff up. Here is my current code for the y-Axis:

```
var commasFormatter = d3.format("1s");

chart.yAxis
  .tickFormat(function(d) { return "$" + commasFormatter(d); })
  .axisLabelDistance(10)
  .axisLabel('Profits')        
  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

After some looking around I was able to figure out a solution.

Wrote a variable for the format, using a `.3s` to reduce the digits to 3 and append a suffix of `M` for million for example.

```
var formatAxis = d3.format('.3s');
```

Then put a function on the `.tickFormat` so replace the `G` with a `B`.

```
.tickFormat(function(val) { return formatAxis(val).replace('G', 'B'); })
```